# Relationship between abstract type and generic interface with the same name

Tags: oop, constructor, interface, fortran, abstract-data-type

Consider the following code.

```
MODULE a


TYPE:: concrete

END TYPE concrete


INTERFACE concrete

PROCEDURE constructor

END INTERFACE concrete


CONTAINS


SUBROUTINE constructor

END SUBROUTINE constructor


END MODULE a
```

As far as I understand, in this context the generic interface `concrete` declares the constructor of type `concrete` to be the subroutine `constructor` (and this is the only way I know to declare a constructor). Now consider the following code.

```
MODULE a


TYPE, ABSTRACT:: abstract

END TYPE abstract


INTERFACE abstract

PROCEDURE what_am_i

END INTERFACE abstract


CONTAINS


SUBROUTINE what_am_i

END SUBROUTINE what_am_i


END MODULE a
```

Here, I have an **abstract** type and a generic interface with the same name, but there cannot be a constructor for the abstract type `abstract`, by definition.

So my question is: is there any relation between an abstract type, a generic interface with the same name, and the procedure inside such interface (in the example, the subroutine `what_am_i`)? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is exactly the same relationship between the type `abstract` and the generic `abstract` as there is between the type `concrete` and the generic `concrete`.

This relationship is, simply, "they have the same name". Although a generic function with the same name as a type can be viewed as a *constructor*, it has no real privileged position.

The definition of a derived type implies a default *structure constructor* with the same name as the derived type, so that

```
type t
  integer i
end type t

type(t) x

x = t(1)

end
```

gives us an object `x` of that type with the expected values.

If instead, we have `x=t(1)` which can be resolved to a specific function `f` we can call that function `f` a constructor if it has function result an object of type `t`.

But there's no reason at all why `f` must return an object of type `t`. Consider

```
module mod
  implicit none

  type t
  end type t

  interface t
     module procedure f
  end interface t

contains

  function f()
    integer f
    f = 1
  end function f

end module mod

use mod
implicit none

print *, t()

end
```

It's hard to call `f` here a constructor.

That's it: no specific function under the generic `abstract` can return a constructed `abstract` object, but each can return something else.  Just as a specific function under the generic `concrete` can return something not of type `concrete`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! So, the definition of an abstract type does not imply a default constructor with the same name, hence the generic interface with the same name is unrelated to the abstract type, other than having the same name (which can perhaps be considered bad practice, since the two are independent from each other). In your example, the type constructor `t` is resolved to `f`, but `f` doesn't return a `t` object. Isn't it pointless to have a constructor to be resolved to a function that does not return an object of that type? If it's not pointless, when would it be useful?

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing to have a specific function under generic `t` which returns something other than an object of type `t`. That's prohibited by your style guide, not by the language specification, though. As a note, Fortran doesn't call the generic `t` a constructor: that's just a word we use to explain the purpose of the generic and its specifics to programmers not compilers. If `f` doesn't construct a `t` then there's no reason to call it a constructor, but the compiler doesn't care what we call `f` in our documentation.